# Laravel: What are functions in routes doing?

Tags: laravel, routes

Can anyone tell why the documentation of Laravel, and others, show functions in routes that return / do something? In what context can you use this?

For example, I try to figure out Molly Connect.

[image]

Here is the corresponding code from https://github.com/mollie/laravel-mollie/blob/master/docs/mollie_connect.md

```
Route::get('login', function () {
    return Socialite::with('mollie')
        ->scopes(['profiles.read']) // Additional permission: profiles.read
        ->redirect();
});

Route::get('login_callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::with('mollie')->user();

    Mollie::api()->setAccessToken($user->token);

    return Mollie::api()->profiles()->page(); // Retrieve payment profiles available on the obtained Mollie account
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just a shortcut, to avoid having to create separate controller files and indirectly referencing those functions. Functionally, your example is no different from doing this:

`Route::get('login_callback', 'LoginController@callback')`

And then, **LoginController.php**

```
class LoginController
{
    public function callback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::with('mollie')->user();
        Mollie::api()->setAccessToken($user->token);
        return Mollie::api()->profiles()->page();
    }
}
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing)